# Why Search-ADAccount is giving different results when Run as Administrator

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am connected as Domain Admin to my DC. When I run the following command in a PowerShell windows, it finds 2 users

```
 Search-ADAccount -UsersOnly -AccountInactive -TimeSpan 90.00:00:00 -SearchBase "OU=myOu,DC=myDomain,DC=local" 
| Where {$_.enabled} | Sort-Object -Property LastLogonDate
```

When I run the same command in a PowerShell **Run as Administrator**, it finds 28 users

it looks like if the PowerShell console is started as Administrator, it can affect the cmdlet's ability to read certain Object and I do not understand why.

Has someone has seen such behavior and can explain why please?

Comment: Just because you're logged in as account with administrator permissions, it doesn't mean you actually get administrator permissions by default. It's been this way since Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can temporarily disable User Account Control (UAC) and then run your PowerShell command which should return the expected results even if you don't invoke Run as Administrator.  That's your quick answer.

The reason is because UAC is not giving you the admin token *which you think* you already have (but don't) when you run PowerShell as a non-administrator (even though you are logged into the DC as a domain administrator).  When UAC is bypassed, such as (1) when it's disabled, (2) has its security level lowered enough, or (3) you invoke Run as Administrator, you have all the rights to read all the properties in AD and all the expected data returns.   But in this case PowerShell will not show values for properties when there is no admin token attached because UAC is enabled on the DC.  It will simply show no values/data (as opposed to throwing an error).  There's a Reddit thread on this [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/activedirectory/comments/elw2n1/searchadaccount_returns_different_results_based/fdky5g6/).

Comment: Interesting Reddit thread indeed and I understand more about the split of the token now, thanks for that. However this doesn't clearly explain behavior like I could see some of the users when UAC is not bypass. So I dig into the Active Directory and I found out that some users had, for reason I do not know, some special permissions like "read Account Restrictions" and "Read Public Informations" for "Authenticated Users" which allow my script running with PowerShell as non-administrator to have enough rights to read the requested properties and show these 2 users.